# How to $set a property to multiple objects in an array but have retain individual reactivity in vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

In my case, I have `data` array with multiple objects

```
data() {
 return {
   selected: 0,
   presetData: [true, true, true],
   data: [
     {
       name: "name 1"
     },
     {
       name: "name 2"
     }
   ]
 };
```

},

then I want to push inside each object in `data` like below

```
setNewData() {
  this.data.forEach((o, i) => {
    this.$set(this.data[i], "time", this.presetData);
  });
},
```

now my with `presetData` pushed into `data` will look like this

```
data: [
    {
      name: "name 1",
      time: [true, true, true]
    },
    {
      name: "name 2",
      time: [true, true, true]
    }
  ]
```

and I want to change individual `time` property of each object, which I use something like below

```
$set(item.time,selected,true)
```

**My Issue**

my issue is, this going to change both objects `time` property. How do I first push/set correctly `presetData` to `data`, below is my entire code , I'm sorry I'm very new to programming, here is the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ALENG/4Lo8swjc/2/)

```
    new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: 0,
      presetData: [true, true, true],
      data: [
        {
          name: "name 1",
        },
        {
          name: "name 2",
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setNewData() {
      this.data.forEach((o, i) => {
        this.$set(this.data[i], "time", this.presetData);
      });
    },
  }
})

  <div id="app">
<button @click="setNewData">Set Data</button>
<br>
<br>
<select v-model="selected">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<div v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  <p>{{item.time}}</p>
  <button @click="$set(item.time,selected,true)">Change True</button>
  <button @click="$set(item.time,selected,false)">Change False</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an object reference issue. Each of your `time` properties references the same array (`presetData`). You can break out of this problem by making shallow copies via [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

You can also avoid `Vue.set()` when assigning new `data` using the same technique

```js
setNewData() {
  this.data = this.data.map(d => ({
    ...d, // create a shallow copy of each data item
    time: [...this.presetData] // add "time" as a shallow copy of presetData
  }))
},
```

To change individual array elements within the `time` property, you need to continue using `Vue.set()`, ie

```js
this.$set(item.time, selected, true)
```

Comment: thanks so much, yes object reference. Would you think I should change my question?

Comment: @aleng no, your question is fine as-is